# I just installed graphite on my mac, but some fonts are huge

Tags: osx-yosemite, graphite

I just installed graphite on OSX, and managed to get the web app running this command:

```
 python /opt/graphite/bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py /opt/graphite
```

I'll eventually move it to ubuntu, but in the mean time, some fonts are enormous:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Try reducing the max font size via the browser. :/

Comment: I chased this down to an issue with the newest version of cairo.  I removed cairo and installed 1.12.6.  I posted the instructions here https://gist.github.com/relaxdiego/7539911

Comment: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I chased this down to an issue with the newest version of cairo. I removed cairo and installed 1.12.6. I posted the instructions here gist.github.com/relaxdiego/7539911

Answer (score 0):

Its the cairocffi that handles the fonts and other display parameters. Sometimes installing only cairo doesn't work. In the above case you should always troubleshoot by ensuring proper and complete installation of the cairocffi package. By complete I mean all the dependencies for cairocffi.
The frequently required are:

```
1. libffi-devel (for rpm based operating systems)
sudo yum install libffi-devel
2. libffi-dev (for debian based operating systems)
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
3. parse_lookup
sudo pip install parse_lookup
```

[This](https://github.com/SimonSapin/cairocffi) is the Github page for cairocffi.